# Black Screen Failure, requires forced reset restart Macbook Pro 15"

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, restart

I'm getting the Black Screen more & more often.  I didn't have it a few months ago & then it started once in a while in a week, now it happens a few times a day, everyday!

My machine is a Macbook Pro 15" from mid 2010 & Apple quarries on the Internet tell me that I can't get it fixed by Apple.

What's going on?

Comment: If you provide us with the Console log at the Time stamp of the event (some 30 lines) we might be able to do something. Console is in your Utility folder.

Comment: I'll try to do this, but I'm not nearly a knowledgable user at the Utility level.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are getting black screen when opening a GPU heavy app or Flash. I am sure that this is a GPU failure. You will also have difficulty at startup later. Try one thing. Download a software called gfxCardStatus. Install it and set the GPU to Intel only. Do not play any games or use Flash. You should be okay.

Comment: I don't use any games or, as far as I know, heavy GPU or flash apps.  However, I have been thinking it occurs more with iPhoto open or opening.  

I'll try gfxCardStatus later today, thanks so much, appreciate your responsiveness.

Comment: How do you set to Intel only?  By disabling switching to save energy?  Thanks.

Comment: @GogogoStopSTOP Click the app in the menu bar. Select Integrated only and make this app load at startup.